# Android: switching from tabs to splitter based on screen size

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an app for a client where the requirements for tablet vs phone form factor switches from tabs for the phone and a split view for larger tablet size devices.

Currently the app works on phone with the tabs and has a main activity that derives from TabActivity.

From what I've read, designing for different size devices generally involves different layouts for different size devices... but what if the activity's base class is different in each layout. (ie:TabActivity for phone, Activity for split view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `TabActivity` has been deprecated for over two years, hopefully you weren't planning on using that anyway.

Hence, use modern tabs, such as a `ViewPager`, in conjunction with `PagerTabStrip` or the tab-style indicator from [the ViewPagerIndicator library](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) (personally, I prefer the look of the latter). Have your UI structured into two fragments. Put the fragments in the `ViewPager` on the phone. Put the fragments in two `FrameLayouts` in a horizontal `LinearLayout` on the tablet.

You also can use tabs in the action bar, or possibly [a `FragmentTabHost`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html), in much the same fashion.